# making queries in SQL PLUS

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

For this Database:

```
CREATE TABLE team (  
  id    CHAR(3),  
  name     VARCHAR2(80) CONSTRAINT nn_team_name     NOT NULL,  
  district VARCHAR2(20) CONSTRAINT nn_team_district NOT NULL,  

CONSTRAINT pk_team  
PRIMARY KEY (id)  
);  

CREATE TABLE game (  
 home,        
 away,  
 round    NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT nn_game_round NOT NULL,  
 spectators NUMBER(5),  
--  
 CONSTRAINT pk_game  
  PRIMARY KEY (home, away),  
--  
 CONSTRAINT fk_game_home  
    FOREIGN KEY (home)  
    REFERENCES team(id),  
 CONSTRAINT fk_game_away  
    FOREIGN KEY (away)  
    REFERENCES team(id),  
--
CONSTRAINT ck_game_round  
 CHECK (round BETWEEN 1 AND 30),  
CONSTRAINT ck_game_spectators
 CHECK (spectators > 0)
);

CREATE TABLE player (  
 nickname        NUMBER(8),  
 name       VARCHAR2(80) CONSTRAINT nn_player_name      NOT NULL,  
 yearOfBirth NUMBER(4)    CONSTRAINT nn_player_yearOfBirth NOT NULL,   
 team                  CONSTRAINT nn_player_team    NOT NULL,  
--
CONSTRAINT pk_player  
  PRIMARY KEY (nickname),  
--
CONSTRAINT fk_player_team  
  FOREIGN KEY (team)  
  REFERENCES team(id),  
--
CONSTRAINT ck_player_yearOfBirth  
  CHECK (yearOfBirth BETWEEN 1950 AND 2000)  
);

CREATE TABLE plays (  
  player,  
  home,         
  away,    
  goals      NUMBER(2) CONSTRAINT nn_plays_goals NOT NULL,  
--
CONSTRAINT pk_plays  
  PRIMARY KEY (player, home, away),  
--
CONSTRAINT fk_plays_player  
   FOREIGN KEY (player) REFERENCES player(nickname),  
CONSTRAINT fk_plays_game  
   FOREIGN KEY (home, away) REFERENCES game(home, away),  
--
CONSTRAINT ck_plays_goals   
   CHECK (goals >= 0)  
);
```

i'm having trouble making the following queries:

- names of the players and their teams, who always played away.

here's my attempt at this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.Name, T.Name
FROM Player P1, Plays P2, Team T, Game G
WHERE P1.team = T.id 
  AND P1.nickname = P2.player
  AND P1.team = G.away
  AND P1.team = P2.away;
```

- Average number of goals by round for the players who were born after 1993 and never played at home.

Here's my attempt:

```
WITH Number_of_Games AS (
  SELECT COUNT(1) AS Number_of_Games, G.Round
  FROM Game G
  GROUP BY G.Round)

SELECT G.Round, SUM(P.goals / N.Number_of_Games) AS Average_goals_per_round
FROM Player P1,Game G INNER JOIN Plays P2 ON (P1.team = P2.away AND G.away = P2.away AND P1.yearofbirth >= '1993')
INNER JOIN Number_of_Games N ON (G.round = n.round)
GROUP BY g.round
ORDER BY g.round;
```

- if i want the id's of the teams with the biggest number of goals against per round , how would i do that ?

HERE'S SOME TESTING DATA:

```
INSERT INTO TEAM (ID, NAME, DISTRICT) VALUES ('MAN','MANCHESTER UNITED','MANCHESTER');
INSERT INTO TEAM (ID,NAME,DISTRICT) VALUES ('CHE','CHELSEA FC','LONDON');
INSERT INTO PLAYER (NICKNAME,NAME,YEAROFBIRTH,TEAM) VALUES('1','VAN PERSIE','1994','MAN');
INSERT INTO PLAYER (NICKNAME,NAME,YEAROFBIRTH,TEAM) VALUES('2','TERRY','1970','CHE');
INSERT INTO GAME(HOME,AWAY,ROUND,SPECTATORS) VALUES ('MAN','CHE','1','15000');
INSERT INTO GAME(HOME,AWAY,ROUND,SPECTATORS) VALUES ('CHE','MAN','2','30000');
INSERT INTO PLAYS(PLAYER,HOME,AWAY,GOALS) VALUES('1','MAN','CHE','2');
INSERT INTO PLAYS(PLAYER,HOME,AWAY,GOALS) VALUES('2','MAN','CHE','1');
INSERT INTO PLAYS(PLAYER,HOME,AWAY,GOALS) VALUES('1','CHE','MAN','1');
```

why is this wrong ? Can anybody help ?

Comment: "names of the players and their teams, who always played away." This sentence is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean players that did not play at home games, or players that participated in all their teams' away games?

Comment: @Mureinik sorry, i mean players that did not play at home games.

Comment: I like the way this question is asked. All table definitions are present and you've provided your attempt at solving it.  I wish more people asked questions this way.

Comment: I agree with @DCookie. The two missing things though are sample data and desired output.

Comment: @peterm how can i submit some data ? Can you tell me why it is wrong ? Because it does makes sense to me, however the output is not what it's supposed to be

Comment: *can i submit some data* There are several ways: 1) in a tabular form in your question 2) in a form of insert statements added to your question 3) better yet create [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and post a link in your question

Comment: @DCookie i've put some testing data

Comment: @peterm i've put some testing data

Comment: Does a team only play one game per round or do they play multiple games per round?

Comment: They only play one game per round @MT0

Comment: Can we have some more test data as there are no players who have never played at home so for the second question there is no rows returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Query 1**

> names of the players and their teams, who always played away

This will get the names of the players who never played at home:

```
SELECT p.name AS player_name,
       t.name AS team_name
FROM   player p
       INNER JOIN
       team t
       ON ( p.team = t.id )
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   plays l
                    WHERE  p.nickname = l.player
                    AND    p.team     = l.home )
```

If you want to enforce that they must have played at least one game then:

```
SELECT p.name AS player_name,
       t.name AS team_name
FROM   player p
       INNER JOIN
       team t
       ON ( p.team = t.id )
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   plays l
                    WHERE  p.nickname = l.player
                    AND    p.team     = l.home )
AND    EXISTS     ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   plays l
                    WHERE  p.nickname = l.player
                    AND    p.team     = l.away -- Although you probably don't need this last line.
                  )
```

**Query 2**

> Average number of goals by round for the players who were born after 1993 and never played at home.

This should get the mean number of goals in each round when only considering the goals scored by players who were born after 1993 and who have never played at home:

```
SELECT AVG( y.goals ),
       g.round
FROM   player p
       INNER JOIN
       plays y
       ON ( p.nickname = y.player AND p.team = y.home )
       INNER JOIN
       game g
       ON ( y.home = g.home AND y.away = g.away )
WHERE  NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM   plays l
                    WHERE  p.nickname = l.player
                    AND    p.team     = l.home )
AND    p.yearOfBirth > 1993
GROUP BY g.round
ORDER BY g.round;
```

**Query 3**

> if i want the id's of the teams with the biggest number of goals against, how would i do that ?

Can be answered using:

```
WITH team_goals AS (
  SELECT SUM( l.goals ) AS total_goals,
         p.team,
         CASE WHEN p.team = l.home THEN l.away
              WHEN p.team = l.away THEN l.home
              ELSE NULL
              END AS opposing_team
  FROM   player p
         INNER JOIN
         plays l
         ON (p.nickname = l.player)
  GROUP BY
         p.team,
         CASE WHEN p.team = l.home THEN l.away
              WHEN p.team = l.away THEN l.home
              ELSE NULL
              END
),
goals_against AS (
  SELECT p.team,
         SUM( q.total_goals ) AS total_goals_against
  FROM   team_goals p
         INNER JOIN
         team_goals q
         ON (    p.team = q.opposing_team
             AND p.opposing_team = q.team)
  GROUP BY p.team
)
SELECT *
FROM   goals_against
WHERE  total_goals_against = ( SELECT MAX( total_goals_against )
                               FROM goals_against );
```

Comment: What i meant is that each team only plays one game per round, but there are more than one game among all the teams

Comment: Updated based on the clarification in your previous comment.

Comment: for the third query, if i wanted the same thing, but for each round, how would i do that ?

Comment: i'd like you to see my answer, as it shows my attempt at the third query

Answer (score 0):

NOT EXISTS should help you with the first question:

```
SELECT DISTINCT P1.Name, T.Name
FROM Player P1 JOIN team T ON p1.team = t.team
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM plays
        WHERE player = p1.name
          AND home = p1.team);
```

I try to avoid the old style joins in the WHERE clause. Use ANSI 92 join syntax for clarity and expanded functionality.

Now expand this query to include only those players born after 1993:

```
SELECT P1.Name, T.Name
FROM Player P1 JOIN team T ON p1.team = t.team
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1
         FROM plays
        WHERE player = p1.name
          AND home = p1.team
          AND year_of_birth <= 1993);
```

Use this query to find the average:

```
  SELECT P1.Name, T.Name, g.round, AVG(p2.goals) "Average Goals"
    FROM Player P1 JOIN team T ON p1.team = t.team
                   JOIN plays p2 ON p1.nickname = p2.player
                   JOIN game g ON p2.away = g.away
   WHERE NOT EXISTS
         (SELECT 1
            FROM plays
           WHERE player = p1.name
             AND home = p1.team
             AND year_of_birth <= 1993))
  GROUP BY p1.name, t.name, g.round;
```

Also, in your games and plays tables, you don't provide a TYPE on your column definitions for some of the columns.

This will get you close. I haven't tested it.

Comment: for the third query, how would i do it ?